# Locking an Express route until request is completed

Tags: node.js, express

I have a POST route which does some heavy operations and it usually takes up to several seconds to complete. The function has some logic to prevent double entity creation by checking if such data is already present in the DB, and it works just fine, if requests are done sequentially. But if they're done concurrently, or at least with a small delay (less than a second), multiple entities can be created, since save operations are not finished yet. Is there a way to prevent such behavior by locking the route for the user until the logic is finished? I thought about using express-rate-limit, but it's about blocking requests for a certain period of time, whilst what I acually need is something like p-queue, but blocking the route only for the user who sent the request, making it still available for others

UPD, use case:
MongoDB+mongoose, pseudocode:

```
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
     /*  some heavy IO here  */
     const entity = await Entity.findOne(req.body);
     if (entity) return res.status(409).end();
     res.json(await new Entity(req.body).save())
```

});

So if clause doesn't work in case of fast requests, since entity isn't created yet

UPD2 similar situation described: https://blog.theodo.com/2019/09/handle-race-conditions-in-nodejs-using-mutex/

UPD3: the best solution for me was to add a compound unique index in schema.

Comment: Express doesn't provide something like this out of the box. You'll need to implement a queue yourself, or find a library that does it.

Comment: It sounds like you have race conditions in how you access your database.  Most databases have features to help you with this type of issue, but we'd have to understand exactly what you're trying to do and see all the relevant database code (might as well show the entire request handler) before anyone here could make any sort of specific recommendation.  Without that, all we can say is to learn how to use atomic operations or database transactions in your database to avoid race conditions.

Comment: FYI, blocking the route is not the right answer.  Much better to make your database access code safe from race conditions.  Much better to fix the way you use the database than to try and put a bandaid over that.

Comment: Added a code example. Another solution i thought of was to check if the similar entity exists on pre-save hook

Answer (score 0):

You could use [async.queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) with a concurrency of 1.

If you only want to queue requests with the same unique id (ie: you can do parallel operations for different entities, but not the same entity), then I would use an object keyed on the entity id, and do something like this:

```
// pseudo-code
const lock = {}
(req, res) => {
   const entityId = req.entityId;
   if (lock[entityId]) {
     // operation already running for this entity
     return res.send('This operation is currently running')
   }
   lock[entityId] = databaseOperation(req)
   .then(() => {
      delete lock[entityId]
      res.send('Success')
   })
   .catch(e => {
      delete lock[entityId]
      res.send(`Failed: ${e.message}`)
   })
}
```

`entityId` could be some user id if you want one request at a time per user.